# How to update a field in a bucket from a field in another bucket in Couchbase?

Tags: python-3.x, couchbase, sql++

Let's say here are two buckets:

```
Bucket A:
   fields: F1, F2, F3,...
Bucket B:
   fields: F1, F2
```

I want to do the following thing in Couchbase:

```
   Let A.F3=B.F2, when A.F1=B.F1
```

But I don't know how to achieve this using either n1ql or python sdk

I've tried "merge into" using n1ql, however I'm quite confused about the "on"
clause which requires the key rather than comparisons

I know that in Oracle, you can do this using "merge into" statement, like:

```
MERGE INTO schema.table1 USING schema.table2 on (schema.table1.col1 = schema.table2.col1) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET schema.table1.col3 = schema.table2.col2
```

How to achieve the same result as the oracle statement above?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO bucketA (KEY d.`key`, VALUE d)
SELECT d
FROM buckerB d
WHERE d.something = "someValue"
```

Comment: 6.50 (currently in beta) ANSI merge is supported